# Denotation of A'

Tags: matrices

I am reading a paper "Storage and Solving of Large Sparse Matrix Linear Equations" and I have encounter a terminology and I am asking for meaning of it. A is 6x6 sparse matrix.
The paragraph is taken from the paper:

> Supposing the large sparse equations as follows:
>
> $Ax = b $
>
> which
> coefficient matrix is n ranks symmetrical positive definite matrix,
> supposing
>
> $M = (S^T S) ^{-1 }$
>
> is symmetrical positive definite matrix, which equals to
>
> $A' x'= b', A'= S A S^T , b'=S b, x'= S^{-T} x$  (equation 2)
>
> Using CG method can directly iterate to get the solutions instead of solving (2) firstly.

Here, $x^2$ is *x* power two. At equation 2 author writes  " $A'=S A S ^T$ ". What is this? Could you please explain? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a bit confusing. $S$ is a change-of-coordinates matrix, and you should have $x' = S^{-1}x$. $A'$ is the representation of $A$ in the new coordinates. But the run-on sentence with "which equals to" makes no sense. Ordinarily, one would try to diagonalize $A$ by using $S$, but that doesn't seem to be happening here. You're saying that $A$ is a positive definite symmetric *sparse* matrix?

Comment: $S$ and it's transpose.

Comment: user645636's answer is correct answer.